# I can't get search working on a UITableView with UISearchBar control

Tags: ios, ios5

I can't get search working on a UITableView. I have declared the delegate etc. in the UITableViewController h file:

```
@protocol searchTanksListDelegate
- (void) searchTanksList:(UISearchBar *) sender textDidChange:(NSString *) searchText;
@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <searchTanksListDelegate> searchDelegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchTanksList;
```

I set the searchTanksList.delegate to self in the UITableViewController viewDidLoad function.

and I have implemented the method thus:

```
- (void)searchTanksList:(UISearchBar *)searchTanksList textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0)
    {
        self.isFiltered = false;
    }
    else {
        self.isFiltered = true;
        self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (tank* thisTank in self.tanks)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [thisTank.tankProduct rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange numberRange = [thisTank.tankNumber rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange productNumberRange = [thisTank.tankProductNumber rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound || numberRange.location != NSNotFound || productNumberRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                 [self.searchResults addObject:thisTank];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The properties have been synthesized etc. - so the code compiles with no errors or warnings... The textDidChange method is not called though when I type!

Comment: I don't get why people aren't conforming their protocols to NSObject at declaration....

Comment: I'm sorry - I am new to objective c/ios development and don't understand what you are saying or how it helps me here... :o)

Comment: It should be this: `@protocol searchTanksListDelegate <NSObject>`

Comment: I have changed that, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just declare the searchBar as a property and make sure the class is set to be a `UISearchBarDelegate`.  Then use the delegate method:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

to process the search.  I can send you a complete example if you need.

Example assuming an Array is what you are filtering:

```
#pragma mark - SearchBar Delegate Methods
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{    
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchText];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";

    workingTableViewData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:originalTableViewData];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];    
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText && searchText.length) {
        [self.workingTableViewData removeAllObjects];    
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in originalTableViewData)
        {
            for (NSString *thisKey in [dictionary allKeys]) {
                if ([thisKey isEqualToString:@"Key1"] || 
                        [thisKey isEqualToString:@"Key2"]) {
                    if ([[dictionary valueForKey:thisKey] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
                        [workingTableViewData addObject:dictionary];
                    }

                } // if ([thisKey isEqualToString:@"Key1"] || [thisKey isEqualToString:@"Key2"])

            } // for (NSString *thisKey in [dictionary allKeys])

        } // for (NSDictionary *dictionary in originalTableViewData)

        [self.myTableView reloadData];

    } // if (searchText && searchText.length)

}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Notes - workingTableViewData and originalTableViewData are both private properties.  originalTableViewData is an NSArray and workingTableViewData is an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Briliant - thank you. I got a bit confused with where to declare the delegate, protocols etc. I have ripped much of that out, and now it works as I wanted! :o) thank you.

Comment: @ElJay method `filterContentForSearchText:` must use Grand Central Dispatch, right? Or GCD construction must be implemented in `searchBar: textDidChange:` method? Or this doesn't matter, where to use it, the only aim is to avoid main thread?

Comment: You are awesome. the simplest breakdown that finally worked with our situation. One question: how can we stop the search results from popping the entire TableView up to take up the entire screen? We have the search bar and tableview a little bit down the view, and as soon as u type in search, the tableview pops up to cover the entire screen (and searchbar remains down in the middle of screen where it was) ? thanks!